# Amazon Cloudfront URL access by only CNAME and not directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am hosting a static website on AWS using Amazon S3 + CloudFront + HTTPS.

I need to ensure that the website is opened by only one of the CNAMEs and not the other (non-www). The S3 domain must also be forwarded to the main WWW domain.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can add a CNAME to a CloudFront Distribution from within the CloudFront console. You can also add a CNAME to a CloudFront distribution in Route53 by selecting to add a CNAME, click the Alias=yes radio button and select the relevant CloudFront resource.

See image below for where this is done in Route 53:

[image]

Comment: CNAME will not forward the request on cloudfront

Comment: @Karan Shah - I'm pretty sure it does. See the image in my answer for where this is done.

Comment: I did mention using CNAME as a part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use S3 to redirect the requests.

> 1. You will firstly need to create two buckets with the names: www.example.com and example.com and provide appropriate bucket
>      policies
> 2. You will then need to redirect all the traffic from example.com S3 bucket to www.example.com by going into static website hosting
>      settings. Check out the below settings
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Now, you have to setup the CNAME in Route53 such that example.com will translate to www.example.com
> 4. Create a distribution for www.example.com and use the alternative CNAME as www.example.com